Get chemical elements as a list with regex
I have this regex: [A-Z][a-z]?\d*|\((?:[^()]*(?:\(.*\))?[^()]*)+\)\d+
This regex returns all simple and nested chemical formulas, for example: O2, SO4, Al2(SO4)3.
I want to get these chemical formulas and use them to write a program to balance chemical equations.
Now I want to improve this regex so that it can separate elements and quantities and put them inside a list or tuple, for example:
O2 -> ('O', 2)
SO4 -> (('S', 1), ('O', 4))
Al2(SO4)3 -> ((('Al', 2), ((('S', 1), ('O', 4)),3)), 1)

This helps me to multiply the second value which is the same quantity by the first values and simplify the equation so that I can solve it. But I don't know how to do it with regex if possible.
If it isn't possible, please tell me a solution for it using python or tell me if you have a better way to simplify these equations or solve them.
I want to avoid using the library as much as possible.

Which library do you want to avoid using?

it’s not possible with regex.
Try this:

def parse_formula(formula):
    elements = re.findall(r'([A-Z][a-z]*)(\d*)', formula)
    parsed_formula = []
    for element, quantity in elements:
        if quantity == '':
            quantity = 1
        else:
            quantity = int(quantity)
        parsed_formula.append((element, quantity))
    return tuple(parsed_formula)

def parse_nested_formula(formula):
    nested_formula = re.findall(r'([A-Z][a-z]*\d*|\([^()]*\)\d*)', formula)
    parsed_nested_formula = []
    for item in nested_formula:
        if item.startswith('('):
            element, quantity = re.match(r'\(([^()]*)\)(\d*)', item).groups()
            parsed_nested_formula.append((parse_nested_formula(element), int(quantity)))
        else:
            parsed_nested_formula.append(parse_formula(item))
    return tuple(parsed_nested_formula)

def simplify_equation(formula):
    parsed_formula = parse_nested_formula(formula)
    simplified_formula = []
    for element, quantity in parsed_formula:
        if isinstance(element, tuple):
            element = simplify_equation(element)
        simplified_formula.append((element, quantity))
    return tuple(simplified_formula)

formula = "Al2(SO4)3"
simplified = simplify_equation(formula)
print(simplified)

This code analyzes the given chemical formula, breaks it into its components, and returns them as a tuple. Then, it simplifies the equation by combining these components and multiplying quantities when necessary. This is a basic solution; you can make it more sophisticated to handle more complex equations.
